My data on my website is not changing in real-time depite making any changes in the data in the code
I am coding a live online game scoring system and require the details to be able to update in real-time. However, the data does not change unless i rerun the code and reload the website. if i change the values of the score i am expecting it change on the website but unfortunately it isnt doing so. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.
This is my python code
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/data_json')
def data_json():
    score_data = [
        {
            "user_name": "User 1",
            "country": "India",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "score": 97
        },

        {
            "user_name": "User 2",
            "country": "India",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "score": 93
        },

        {
            "user_name": "User 3",
            "country": "United States",
            "state": "New York",
            "score": 85
        },

        {
            "user_name": "User 4",
            "country": "India",
            "state": "New Delhi",
            "score": 80
        }
    ]
    return jsonify(score_data)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    score_data = data_json()
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        scores=score_data.json
    )

This is my HTML code
<table class="table table-dark table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">User Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">State</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table_body">
    {% for score in scores %}
    <tr>
        <td id="user_name_{{ score.user_name }}"> {{ score.user_name }}</td>
        <td id="country_{{ score.user_name }}"> {{ score.country }}</td>
        <td id="state_{{ score.user_name }}"> {{ score.state }}</td>
        <td id="score_{{ score.user_name }}"> {{ score.score }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
            fetch('/data_json').then(
                response => response.json()
            ).then(
                data =>
                    data.forEach(score =>
                        updateElement(score)
                    )
            )
        }, 1000
    );

    function updateElement(score){
        Object.entries(score).forEach(([k,v]) => {
            let element = document.getElementById(k + "_" + score.id);
            // Get Previous value first
            let previousValue = element.innerHTML;

            // If Previous value is not equal to the new value, change it!
            if (previousValue !== v.toString()) {
                element.innerHTML = v.toString();
            }
        })
    }


</script>


Why would it change? You've literally hard-coded the JSON payload that gets sent to the frontend

any recommendation on what i should change for it to be able to change?

That would be akin to writing the app for you. You have zero mechanism here to update the data, so it's not even a tweak to something you already have. You would need to look into something like AJAX

I had thought the fetch API would be enough to take in and change the data but thanks ill look into AJAX.

Sorry, that's my bad. The fetch API would do it too but the data inside def data_json(): can never change, so it'll just give back the same payload every single time. You have no mechanism in place to update any of its values (baking it into the function won't really help here, you'd want something more database-like with routes that can update the data)

You should put the JSON in a file that the data_json() function reads. Then you can edit the file and it will return the modified data.

@roganjosh I suspect they're editing the python file and expecting it to start returning the updated data. But until you restart the script, it's still running the previous version.

@Barmar agreed. I think it's just too much effort to fix this up as it's a big re-write

And if you're just returning static JSON data, why bother with Flask in the first place? Just have the URL point directly to the file.

Thanks a lot guys, I was editing the python file hoping to return  the updated data, I will try using a separate file for the JSON do that the data_json() function can read. Its my first flask application and so im not so clear about some of the topics. Again appreciate all the input.
